# Cannot get an Azure SQL Server query to execute from a small kafka consumer application using vertx and the JDBC connector

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I am trying to insert data into an azure sql server using a java Kafka consumer application. I have a connection to the database confirmed.

Here is the method.

```
private void poll(KafkaConsumer<String, JsonObject> consumer) {
    vertx.setPeriodic(TIME_OUT_MS,
        timerId -> consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(POLL_MS)).onSuccess(records -> {
          for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            KafkaConsumerRecord<String, JsonObject> record = records.recordAt(i);
            System.out.println(
                "key=" + record.key() + ",value=" + record.value() + ",partition=" +
                    record.partition() + ",timestamp=" + record.timestamp() + ",offset=" + record.offset());

            Weather weather = toParams(record);
            JsonObject datasourceConfig = PropertiesHelper.getDatasourceProperties();
            JDBCPool pool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx, datasourceConfig);
            String query = "INSERT INTO database.dbo.table (captureTime, waveHeight, wavePeriod, waveDirection, windSpeed, windDirection) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            pool
                .getConnection()
                .onFailure(e -> {
                  System.out.println("failed to get a connection: " + e.toString());
                })
                .onSuccess(conn -> {
                  conn
                      .preparedQuery(query)
                      .execute(Tuple.of(weather.getCaptureTime(), weather.getWaveHeight(), weather.getWavePeriod(),
                          weather.getWaveDirection(), weather.getWindSpeed(), weather.getWindDirection()))
                      .onFailure(e -> {
                        System.out.println("failed to execute query: " + e.toString());
                        conn.close();
                      })
                      .onSuccess(rows -> {
                        System.out.println("successfully added row " + weather.getCaptureTime());
                        conn.close();
                      });
                });
          }
        }).onFailure(cause -> {
          System.out.println(
              "Something went wrong when polling " + cause.toString());
          cause.printStackTrace();

          vertx.cancelTimer(timerId);
        }));
  }
```

I think the issue is with the

```
String query = "INSERT INTO {database.dbo.table} (captureTime, waveHeight, wavePeriod, waveDirection, windSpeed, windDirection) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

query line, but I'm not sure what to try next.

My issue is that no matter how I word my sql query string I get one of two errors. If I use the full databasename.dbo.tablename in the query I get `"Reference to database and/or server name is not supported in the version of SQL server"`. But if I use any variation of tablename and/or dbo I get an `"invalid object"` error instead.  I think I have tried most variations of the name but so far no success.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Once run the same query in SSMS to check getting error or not?

Comment: Instead of fowudatabase.dbo.weather just mention weather and try once.

Comment: @Bhavani The query runs ok when i just use weather or dbo.weather in  the Azure query editor. But does not work if I do that from the query statement in the method.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with Kafka. Refactor your SQL code to an external function and test it separately. Also worth pointing out that Kafka Connect JDBC Sink can probably already do what you want.

Comment: Q: It sounds like you might have "connected" to one database ... but you're querying a *different* database (i.e. making a cross-DB query).  Look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/ and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical?view=azuresql

Comment: INSERT into table?  that's a SQL keyword.  You should never name a table "table".  Leave off "database.dbo" as well.  Should just be a sensible table name.

Comment: @duffymo: I suspect the OP probably just substituted example names "database.dbo.table" for his *real* schema.  That's what I'd do, anyway :)

Comment: I don't see how telling me that table is named WEATHER_DATA gives away any secrets.  Silly.

Comment: @duffymo - I did just replace the real schema name with database.dbo.table.

Comment: @Paulsm4 - thanks for the heads up. I did wonder about this but I'm still not sure it's the right way to go about it. I'm not really cross-querying as I only have one table. I just want to add data to it from a kafka topic. As you can tell I'm new to all this. I'll have another look at the links you provided and keep trying.

Comment: You'd find this easier if you decomposed your problem some more.  Write a repository class whose sole responsibility is to deal with the database.  Unit test it until it works perfectly.  Inject an instance into the Kafka component that handles messaging.  It's called the single responsibility principle.  The code you posted is doing too much.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It was a properties error with the datasource.
Turns out
`props.put("url","jdbc:sqlserver://****.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=****")`

is correct, not

`props.put("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://****.database.windows.net:1433);`

`props.put("database", "****");`